# Write `var0, var1, var2, ..., var10` in a buffer

Tags: keyboard-macros, print

Most of the times there is no need to write manually many variables with the same name and a different index, like

```
var0, var1, var2, var3, ..., var9
```

because one can use arrays, vectors or whatever the language offers.

Anyway, I just needed to write manually ten variables as shown above. What is the fastest way to do it with emacs?

I guess that the fastest way is to write some elisp code. 
I tried doing it with this code

```
(setq i 0)
    (while (< i 10) (print (format "var%d, " i)) (setq i (+ 1 i))
```

followed by `(insert-last-message)` defined [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154098/copy-the-last-emacs-message-into-the-current-buffer).
It does not work (I get "(#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)").

What's wrong here? Is there any faster way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest way is to use the macro counter:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> *starts recording a macro*

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> *inserts 0 as the initial value of the counter*

<kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>M-0</kbd> *repeat the following 10 times*

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> *execute the macro*

Comment: Cool! Is it possible to make the macro counter start from another number?

Comment: If you start recording your macro with `F3`, you can give it a numeric argument with the number to start from.

Comment: Don't forget to delete the extra comma at the end. :)

Comment: A numeric prefix argument means the same thing to `C-x (` as it does to `<f3>`, so you don't *need* to use the function key for that (but it's shorter, so you may as well).  If for any reason you can't, note that `C-x C-k TAB` also inserts-and-increments the counter.

Answer (score 3):

`print` will output to the echo area rather than putting stuff in your buffer. You're looking for `insert` and `dotimes`:

```
(dotimes (i 10) (insert (format "var%d, " i)))
```

(alternatively you can use keyboard macros for this)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a macro just as @choroba did (with `F3` in place of `C-x (` and `F4` instead of `C-x e`, for brevity and to be able to easily specifying a non-zero starting number, as @DoMiNeLa10 mentioned), but if you want a possibly more ergonomic solution, there is abo-abo's [tiny](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny) package. You'd type `m0, 9|var%d` into your buffer, and then execute `tiny-expand` and it would replace `m0, 9|var%d` with:

```
var0, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9
```

for you. (I used it just now to type that.)

Notice that the comma and space between `0` and `9` are used as a separator, that is, you don´t get an extra one at the end like you would with the most straightforward macro.

Answer (score 1):

If you use lispy (https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy), you can do this:

1. Enter `(s-join ", " (loop for i below 10 collect (format "var%s" i)))` into your elisp buffer. At the end of the sexp, type xr which will evaluate and replace the sexp with a string in quotes. Type C-b to get the cursor on the last quote, then type C-u " to unquote the string.

alternatively, if you type the code @rpluim suggested, and type xr, it will also replace it with about the same thing, you just have to delete a nil and the last comma.

I am not sure it is faster than a macro counter, but since I like lispy, it is a nice solution for me.

Comment: There is also the builtin `string-join` (which takes its arguments in the opposite order), if you don't have `s` installed.

Comment: @Omar `string-join` is built-in, but it requires `(eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))`. Just like `loop` requires `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))` (though `cl-loop` from `cl-lib.el` is generally preferred to `loop` from `cl.el`; see [`(cl) Organization`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Organization.html)).